# Points on a line and lines through a point in projective geometry notation

Tags: projective-geometry

> Let $(P, L, I)$be a projective plane. For a line $l \in L$ let $p(l)= \{ p  \in P
> | pIl \}$ be the points
> on $l$,and for a point $p \in P$ let $l(p)= \{ l  \in L
> | pIl \}$ be the lines through $p$.
>
> From: Jürgen Richter-Gebert (auth.) - Perspectives on Projective Geometry A Guided Tour Through Real and Complex Geometry,page-44

What does $pIl$ mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ and $L$ are arbitrary sets and their elements are *considered* as 'points' and 'lines', respectively.

$I$ is a *relation* between these sets, called the *incidence relation* (it contains certain pairs $(p,l)$ with $p\in P,\ l\in L$).
$p\,I\,l$ is the *infix notation* for expressing $(p,l)\in I$, which is interpreted as 'point $p$ lies on line $l$'.

$p(l)$ is the set of all points of line $l$ and $l(p)$ is the set of all lines through point $p$.

Comment: Nice cat! And thanks!